# git --bare clone analogue for Hg (Mercurial)

Tags: git, mercurial

I want to checkout only history of a repository.

Does there any option to clone history as like as `git --bare clone <repo_url>` option?

Comment: I don't know why you changed to accept the other answer as correct, as you asked about `clone`, not about transforming an existing repository to a bare one. I updated my answer with the information @Ry4anBrase provided.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@vampire has your answer for a new clone.  For an existing one `hg update null` does the job. That checks out the `null` revision, which is the revision before revision 0, and contains no files.  If you check out that revision you local files go away and you've got a bare clone.

Comment: As this does not really answer the question, but "just" provides additional interesting side-information, this should have been an edit to my answer, not an own one I think. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. :( I up-voted yours, and it was already selected as correct at the time.  I just know that by the time people are asking this question they've usually got a non-bare clone and would rather save themselves the network traffic.  He should pick your answer.

Answer (score 7):

I don't use Mercurial, but from the help I'd say the nearest you will get is

> -U    --noupdate  the clone will include an empty working directory (only a repository)

**Update as per answer of @Ry4anBrase:**

For an existing repository `hg update null` deletes all local files. This checks out the `null` revision, which is the revision before revision 0, and contains no files. If you check out that revision you local files go away and you've got a bare clone as a result.